# error: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds

Tags: java

I am getting the following compile error:

javac -cp "/Users/myname/Desktop/Projects/Project/target/jarname.jar" Util.java -Xlint:unchecked

```
Util.java:51: error: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
            tags = Arrays.stream(tagArray).collect(Collectors.toList());
                                                  ^
    equality constraints: List<String>
    upper bounds: ArrayList<String>,Object
  where R,A,T are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)
    A extends Object declared in method <R,A>collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream
1 error
```

Now my impression is that you should be able to get all of the Stream elements into a list this way.

I am somewhat new to Java... what am I not understanding here?

This is the function that is causing the issue in Util.java:

```
public static GoogleMerchantDetailsDto convertGoogleMerchantDetails(SqlRow row) {
    Array rawTagArray = (Array) row.get("tags");
    ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList();
    if (rawTagArray != null) {
        String[] tagArray = Util.toStringArray(rawTagArray);
        tags = Arrays.stream(tagArray).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    String distanceFrom = String.format("%,.1f", row.getDouble("distance_from"));
    String latitude = String.format("%,.6f", row.getDouble("latitude"));
    String longitude = String.format("%,.6f", row.getDouble("longitude"));
    GoogleMerchantDetailsDto googleMerchant = GoogleMerchantDetailsDto.builder().withId(row.getString("id"))
            .withName(row.getString("name")).withTags(tags).withDistanceFrom(distanceFrom).withLatitude(latitude)
            .withLongitude(longitude).withIsFavorite(row.getBoolean("is_favorite"))
            .withWaitlist(row.getInteger("waitlist")).withAddress1(row.getString("vicinity")).build();
    return googleMerchant;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the sourcecode for `Util.java` as well?

Comment: `toList()` returns `List`, not `ArrayList`. If you specifically need `ArrayList` (hint: you don't), use `toCollection(ArrayList::new)`.

Comment: What he says is: use `List<String> tags` instead if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @shmosel sorry, I inherited the code, and I am not a big Java dev.

Comment: Can one of you write an answer that refactors the code so I can see exactly what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ArrayList<String>` to `List<String>` instead,
like this:

```java
public static GoogleMerchantDetailsDto convertGoogleMerchantDetails(SqlRow row) {
    Array rawTagArray = (Array) row.get("tags");
    List<String> tags = new ArrayList();
    if (rawTagArray != null) {
        String[] tagArray = Util.toStringArray(rawTagArray);
        tags = Arrays.stream(tagArray).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    // ... rest of the method ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, it's inherited code and I just have not done a huge amount of Java development. I'm not totally educated on all of the data structures (or the difference between ArrayList and List, though I have read up on it now)

Comment: Generally you should use the most abstract type (in this case the `interface List`) if you can.